# what else to do to enable XML-RPC in ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd, xml-rpc

I have configure ejabberd on my server but when i tried to access ejabberd i am getting the error the port 4560/rpc2 is not responding.I have uncomment out XML-RPC in ejabberd.yml file but after uncomment the ejabberd stop working.Here is the code which i uncomment.

```
  - 
##     port: 4560
##   module: ejabberd_xmlrpc
##   maxsessions: 10
##   timeout: 5000
##   access_commands: 
##   admin:
## commands: all
##         options: []
```

i have search almost everything what else i have to install or uncomment to enable this port and function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have installed the latest version of ejabberd-20.01 so now i am not getting xml-rpc error any more.But now i am facing user register error.

Answer (score 0):

> I have configure ejabberd on my server

You don't mention what ejabberd version you are using. I guess the latest released, ejabberd 19.09.1

> but when i tried to access ejabberd i am getting the error the port 4560/rpc2 is not responding.

That may be because you must configure a listener for port 4560 in ejabberd.yml

> I have uncomment out XML-RPC in ejabberd.yml file but after uncomment the ejabberd stop working.Here is the code which i uncomment.

You don't mention what error messages are shown in the ejabberd log files. Was it like this?

11:22:26.482 [critical] Failed to start ejabberd application: Invalid value of option listen->3: Unknown option: maxsessions.

It means the option maxsessions is no longer supported by ejabberd_xmlrpc.

I configure it like this:

```
  -
    port: 4560
    module: ejabberd_xmlrpc
```

Then I do a simple test, visiting this website:

```
http://localhost:4560/
```

And the ejabberd_xmlrpc replies as expected that this GET query is not supported:

```
400 Bad Request
```

Comment: I am getting an 4560/RPC2): failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it and error  xmlrpc_is_fault() expects parameter 1 to be array.