# xmlrpc getting an error xmpp user register

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have working o ejabberd and xmpp but while register user i am getting an error

`Notice: xmlrpc: Error -118 A problem '{error,access_rules_unauthorized}' occurred executing the command register with arguments`

I am using this code

```
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request($command, $params, (array('encoding' => 'utf-8')));

    $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
            'method' => "POST",
            'header' => "User-Agent: XMLRPC::Client mod_xmlrpc\r\n" .
            "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n" .
            "Content-Length: " . strlen($request),
            'content' => $request
    )));
    // echo '<pre>'; print_R($context); die;
    $file = file_get_contents('http://192.168.1.22:4560/RPC2', false, $context);
    //echo '<pre>'; print_R($file); die;
    $response = xmlrpc_decode($file);


    if (xmlrpc_is_fault($response)) {
        trigger_error("xmlrpc: $response[faultString] ($response[faultCode])");
    } else {
        return $response;
    }
```

I have tried everything but still getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

So, you finally solved the previous problem you had in [what else to do to enable XML-RPC in ejabberd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59944077/what-else-to-do-to-enable-xml-rpc-in-ejabberd/59965111?noredirect=1#comment106171635_59965111) ? You can add an explanation there to help other people, or at least mark the problem as solved, so other people don't waste their time investigating something that you no longer care about.

Comment: I have installed the latest version so thats why the xml rpc problem is solved.